# What is the keyword for local currency in chained angular currency filter? (without custom directive)

Tags: angularjs, view

I have looked in documentation, but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.
I also know I can make a custom filter to handle this use case, but I wanted to avoid doing that.

My goal is to show a currency result that has no decimal places, but also uses the default / local currency type.
That is to say, I don't want to specify a particular type of currency, I'd just like the default type.

I know that I can chain together number filters and currency filters if I provide an explicit type of currency (eg `| currency: "$" : 0`  ), however, I can't assume which country

(I've noticed that if I put in any nonsense word without quotes as a parameter, it'll work.  i.e.- where 'foobar' is below. I don't want to use a nonsense word, though, I'd like to do it the right way.)

```
<span>
    {{ctrl.totalSum | currency: foobar : 0}}
</span>
```

So far, I have tried: `null`, `"null"`, `local`, `"local"`, `""`, `"undefined"`, and empty content.  I can't seem to determine what the proper keyword is to indicate I want the default value.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it appears that I can use `undefined` as a parameter, as described on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

It appears to be a primitive type that can be passed in.
The following syntax worked for me:

```
<span>
       {{ctrl.totalSum | currency: undefined : 0}}
</span>
```

After looking through the base angular library, I see that there is a check for whether this parameter is undefined.  By passing in a primitive undefined type, it prompts the local symbol logic:

```
    return function(amount, currencySymbol){
        if (isUndefined(currencySymbol)) currencySymbol = formats.CURRENCY_SYM;
            return formatNumber(amount, formats.PATTERNS[1], formats.GROUP_SEP, formats.DECIMAL_SEP, 2).
            replace(/\u00A4/g, currencySymbol);
```

};
}